# Ios : How to align labels like whatsapp chat message label and time label?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, chat

In whatsapp, if the message is very short, the text and time are in the same row.
If the message is long, the time is in the bottom right corner - the text coming above it.

How can i achieve this using Storyboard in Ios

[image]

Comment: use table view and 2 cell with left and right content. Its not just label is has image and time label too.

Comment: @Bista I want to align the time label as in image in single cell

Comment: @Arunkrishna I want to achieve the exact same thing as you mentioned in the question. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try using something like this to define last line width (Maybe you'll have to tweak text container a bit more for your case):

```
public func lastLineMaxX(message: NSAttributedString, labelWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
    let labelSize = CGSize(width: bubbleWidth, height: .infinity)
    let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
    let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: labelSize)
    let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: message)

    // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
    layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
    textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

    // Configure textContainer
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0

    let lastGlyphIndex = layoutManager.glyphIndexForCharacter(at: message.length - 1)
    let lastLineFragmentRect = layoutManager.lineFragmentUsedRect(forGlyphAt: lastGlyphIndex,
                                                                  effectiveRange: nil)

    return lastLineFragmentRect.maxX
}
```

Then you can decide if there is enough place for your date label in the last line or not

usage example:

```
// you definitely have to set at least the font to calculate the result
// maybe for your case you will also have to set other attributes
let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.label.text, 
                                        attributes: [.font: self.label.font])
let lastLineMaxX = lastLineMaxX(message: attributedText, 
                                labelWidth: self.label.bounds.width)
```

Comment: This is not returning last line width. Its returning total width of all words

Comment: @Arunkrishna How did you check it? I'm definitely sure it returns last line width. I tried it with UILabel placing black line above it at coordinate calculated by this function and that line was exactly behind the last symbol in the last line of text. I added usage example at the end of the answer. Hope this could help

Comment: My label width is not constant. I think thats what causing issue for me. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Arunkrishna You are welcome. I don't think such layout is possible to setup with just some constraints in NIB-file. So you will have to calculate the size of cells in code. And to calculate size of cell you probably will calculate size of text according to its' maximum width. And after that you will know the label width which will let you to calculate last line width which in turn will let you decide whether you have enough space for date label or you have to extend cell height to put date label under message

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Swift to Objective-C**

```
- (void)lastlineWidth {

    NSDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.label.font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

    NSAttributedString *message = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.label.text attributes:attrsDictionary];

    CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(self.label.bounds.size.width, INFINITY);
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:labelSize];
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:message];

    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];

    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0;
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0;

    NSInteger lastGlyphIndex = [layoutManager glyphIndexForCharacterAtIndex:message.length-1];

    CGRect lastLineRect = [layoutManager lineFragmentUsedRectForGlyphAtIndex:lastGlyphIndex effectiveRange:nil];

    NSLog(@"lastLineWidth = %f", lastLineRect.size.width);
}
```