# How to make Label first line text less from other line

Tags: ios

I want something like this, first line text should be wrap according to rating button width and rating button width may be less or greater.

[image]

If anyone have idea please give your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK `UILabel` doesn't have such feature but you can achieve this behaviour by using UITextView. You can tweak it to look like your label and then set exclusion path for its' text container like this:

```
let exclusionPath = UIBezierPath(rect: textView.convert(button.frame, from: button.superview))
textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [exclusionPath]
```

If you also want to change button width according to the available width in the first line, then you can set excluded path frame with minimal width (according to text width and insets in button) and than calculate available space in first row similar to the way mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765460/ios-how-to-align-labels-like-whatsapp-chat-message-label-and-time-label/51767161#51767161) (it shows how to calculate the width of the last line but doing the same for the first one is quite similar)

Comment: This is working but a little bit issue with diff size of screen.

Comment: @VikasRajput what kind of?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this codes, it will help you

```
myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])

myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))

myMutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "SFUIText-Bold", size: 14)!, range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))

labName.attributedText = myMutableString
```